# Solve the initial value problem $u'(t)=u^2(t)+t,\;u(0)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the following initial value problem: $$\begin{cases}u'(t)=u^2(t)+t\\u(0)=1\end{cases}$$ This is a first-order nonlinear equation. The only method I know, to solve such an equation, is separation of variables. But this seems not to be applicable here.

If I can't solve it with elementary methods: Can we tell whether a global valid solution exist or a solution would blow up in finite time?

Comment: This is so-called Riccatti's equation, which cannot be solved by elementary methods. Comparison with $\dot u=u^2$ implies that there are no global solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The solution below, which is expressed in terms of Airy functions and dérivatives of Airy functions, could be expressed in terms of particular Bessel functions, thanks to the relationships between those kinds of functions.

[image]

Comment: Hi @jjacquelin very nice solution.  Congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

Using Maple I am obtaining the following solution in terms of Airy functions

[image]

In terms of Bessel functions the solution takes the form

[image]

The corresponding curve for this solution is

[image]